# Travel from USA to India with $8K cash

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal, money

I will be travelling from USA to India. I will be travelling with my spouse. Can we carry $8K in cash. $4K will be with my wife and $4K will be with myself. We are keeping the money for emergency and buying items while we are in transit in Doha, Qatar.

So the query is can I carry $8K total in cash. My credit card limit is very less, 1K.

Comment: Why do you need to carry cash ?  Why not use your credit card to buy ?

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: @SJuan76 The question is "can we carry $8K in cash?"

Comment: Did you do a simple Google search first?

Comment: Can you use a debit card?  In Doha, you most certainly can find an ATM anywhere without a big fee.  Especially in the airport.

Comment: Unless you plan to do some Really Serious Shopping in Doha, you're carrying way too much cash. If you prebook your hotel with transportation (or got it from Qatar for free), and apply for a free transit visa on Qatar web site (must do so at least 7 days before departure!), you'd only need something like $50 max for food if your stay is more than overnight - and even there many places accept credit cards. I transited through Doha many times with overnight stays, and still have no idea how Qatari Riyal even look like.

Comment: I really find the downvotes to be perplexing.  The question is straightforward.

Answer (score 12):

There are two distinct aspects of this question

> 1. Can you carry $8,000 while leaving the US?

[US CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/kw/DECLARING%20CURRENCY%20WHEN%20LEAVING%20US/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ5MjYwMjM2MC9zaWQvRGQzX2V1Z24%3D) website says that

> How much currency / money / monetary instruments can I bring into the
>   U.S.?
>
> There is **no limit on the amount of money that can be taken out** of or
>   brought into the United States. However, if a person or persons
>   traveling together and filing a joint declaration (CBP Form 6059-B)
>   have $10,000 or more in currency or negotiable monetary instruments,
>   they must fill out a "Report of International Transportation of
>   Currency and Monetary Instruments" FinCEN 105 (former CF 4790).
>
> Please be aware, if **persons/family members traveling together have
>   $10,000 or more, they cannot divide the currency between each other** to
>   avoid declaring the currency.
>
> For example, if one person is carrying $5,000 and the other has
>   $6,000, they have a total of $11, 000 in their possession and must
>   report it on a FinCEN 105. If a person or family fails to declare
>   their monetary instruments in amounts of over $10,000, their monetary
>   instrument(s) may be subject to forfeiture and could result in civil
>   and or criminal penalties.

Thus, you are entitled to carry $8,000 when travelling together without any paper-work.

> 2. Can you bring $8,000 into India?

According to FAQ on website of [Reserve Bank of India](https://m.rbi.org.in//SCRIPTS/FAQView.aspx?Id=66#q5)

> How much foreign exchange can be brought in while visiting India?
>
> Ans. A person coming into India from abroad **can bring with him foreign exchange without any limit**. However, if the aggregate value of the foreign exchange in the form of currency notes, bank notes or travellers cheques brought in exceeds USD 10,000 or its equivalent and/or **the value of foreign currency alone exceeds USD 5,000 or its equivalent, it should be declared to the Customs Authorities** at the Airport in the Currency Declaration Form (CDF), on arrival in India.

Unlike US, India makes no mention about people travelling together and just states the limits as "per person". If both you and your spouse hold $4,000 each, you should be fine. Note that even if you were travelling alone, you could bring $8,000 into India but in that case you would have to declare it at the customs.

Assuming you are merely transiting in Doha, you don't have to worry about currency import/export regulations there. [IATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/QA-Qatar-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm#currency) states they have no limits on currency anyway.